# Adding Multiple Marks on map in Java

Tags: java, android, api

I am creating an app that shows all locations of a specific business. There are around 100 locations and I'm looking for a way to add markers for all of them. Do I have to get the Lat and Long of each location or is there an easier way to mark all locations?

Comment: yes you should have an arraylist of latitude and logitude to add markers

Answer (score 0):

call the below function with different LatLng to add much markers as you want

```
 public void addMarkers(LatLng latLng){
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("title if you want");
   
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }
```